# Laravel 4 Response Headers: deny ajax request based on origin domain

Tags: header, laravel, httpresponse, cors, laravel-4

I'm trying to create a simple method to restrict access to data based upon the domain from which an HTTP request originates (i.e. CORS basically).

To give some brief background: (I'm using latest Laravel 4) - In this app, data is used off-site by customers. I want to give the customers the ability to restrict HTTP requests to access that data based upon the origin. So that only requests from their website can access that data via the API.

i.e. for arguments sake: imagine a script on http://mycustomer.com makes an Ajax call to http://myapp.com/api/customers_data --- I want to only allow requests from http://mycustomer.com, and deny all others.

Relevant code I've currently got:

```
    // i.e. 'http://mycustomer.com';
    $allow_domain = User::settings->domain;

    $headers = array(
       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => $allow_domain,
    );

    return Response::make($JSON_data, 200, $headers);
```

But this doesn't seem to be working to deny requests originating from other domains.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: To answer this question, after many hours of hair-pulling it was the classic "output before sending headers" issue". I was error logging one of my utility functions, which was outputting pre-header.

Also, as a note, if anyone has a similar issue: there is no suffix backslash on the allowed domain. i.e. 'http://allow.com/' fails, but 'http://allow.com' works.